# getting csv result in one line

Tags: php, csv

when i am trying to upload csv file in php and exporting fields in php using fgetcsv function, it is returned all result in one array instead of comma separated.
I have 2 csv file but in one its working and in another it is showing all values in one array 
like this:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Name 
    [1] => Number
    [2] => Tax Center
John12
    [3] => 2122561681
    [4] => 71 West 19 
John13
    [5] => 6462102791
    [6] => 72 West 19 
John14
    [7] => 9144190749
    [8] => 73 West 19 
John15
    [9] => 8602867600
    [10] => 74 West 19 
John16
    [11] => 8602435024
    [12] => 75 West 19 
John17
    [13] => 8602429299
    [14] => 76 West 19 
John18
    [15] => 2034838300
    [16] => 77 West 19
```

here is my code to get only first row of csv

```
if(($handle = fopen($file , "r")) !== FALSE) 
                    {
                            $fileAdded  = true;
                            $adcon      = 0;

                            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) 
                                {
                                    /*echo '<pre>';
                                    print_r($data);
                                    echo '</pre>';*/
                                    $first = $data;
                                    break;                                  
                                }

                            fclose($handle);
                    }
```

Comment: From the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php): `Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.`

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkBaker, now its working